# window.open event listeners not working in Android 4.4.2

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a PhoneGap app that uses the InAppBrowser to load the Google login experience. As such, I need an event listener that detects when the browser changes location. The setup below works perfectly fine on all Android versions except for 4.4.2, as best as I can tell; the event listener fires and all is good.

However, on Android 4.4.2 I can't seem to get any event listeners to fire for the window; loadstart, onload, onscroll, etc. Nothing seems to fire. Can't seem to find any solutions on Google or StackOverflow, unfortunately.

Not sure what additional information is needed/useful, but happy to provide anything.

```
var auth_window = window.open(auth_url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

auth_window.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
     alert("blah")
})
```

-

*****Update*****

I've been able to get the listener to fire by backing out of InAppBrowser and opening it again. I have no clue why it would work in this case but not otherwise, though. Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Constantly calling exec will force process the messages.

```
setInterval(function () {
    cordova.exec(null, null, '', '', [])
}, 200);
```

I am using this hack in meteor-phonegap-oauth, https://github.com/jperl/meteor-phonegap-oauth/blob/badfb932bb0b525a32c35115eb75edb8d21bbf57/patch_window.js#L20-L29

This will also fix the problem that plugins do not invoke their callback until the next plugin action, ex: [Cannot use asynchronous methods in Cordova 3.4. Onsuccess is not called after the first call of plugin method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23934173/230462)

Answer (score 0):

You might have an old PhoneGap/Cordova version that doesn't support Android 4.4.x very well.
In that case you should update PhoneGap/Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm running PhoneGap 3.3, so I'm not sure that's the issue.

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to try version 3.4 - just in case. It apparently has numerous Android fixes. (http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/03/04/phonegap-3-4-release/)
I've solved compatibility issues before with just upgrading.

Comment: Few Jquery functions are also not working on 4.4.x but working fine under 4.4.x . i am using cordova 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
window.open("http://google.com", '__blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var auth_window = window.open(auth_url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

I think the above method's 3rd parameter is Options, and there's only one option which is "location" yes or no, there's no option like "toolbar" for this method.

so remove the extra option after comma, and I think you would be fine.

Here's explanation from phone gap documentation

> options: options for the InAppBrowser (String) (Optional, Default:
>   "location=yes")
>
> The options string must not contain any blank space, each feature name
>   and value must be separated by a comma. Only the value below is
>   supported:
>
> **> location - set to 'yes' or 'no' to turn the location bar on or off for
>   the InAppBrowser**

Comment: Whether this is correct or not depends on which version of PhoneGap is being used. But your quote from the documentation indicates that their *can* be more than one option (option*s*, *each*) - as is in their documentation here for example: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open