# Cordova window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL only firing callback after third call

Tags: cordova

I am trying to write a basic Cordova App (my first) that involves writing to a file that needs to be accessible to read in other apps.

I have a simple 'export' button that calls a function containing window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL to obtain the android root file system.

```
Function writeFile(){
    console.log("write File");

    var rootFilePath = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/'; // note that this is android specific
    
    
    //attempt to retrieve file system
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(rootFilePath, resolveSuccessCallback, errorCallback);

    function resolveSuccessCallback(fs) {
        console.log("File System OK");
        // other code here to create directory, file etc
    };

    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.code);        
        }

};
```

The issue is that I only get a callback after the export button is pressed the third time - at which point it works OK.

Comment: What is the console output when you debug with Chrome Device Inspector the app running on the phone? That errorCallback function is there just to answer your question..

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue raised here: [Cannot use asynchronous methods in Cordova 3.4. Onsuccess is not called after the first call of plugin method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934173/cannot-use-asynchronous-methods-in-cordova-3-4-onsuccess-is-not-called-after-th)

Adding a timer to regularly call cordova.exec solved the problem

```
setInterval(function () {
    cordova.exec(null, null, '', '', [])
}, 200);
```

But it still does not explain why this issue is happening with a standard plugin. I am using an older version of cordova (6.3.1) which is the stock version shipped with the visual studio cordova pluginin. Although I have a solution now. I would like to understand why this is happening - was this a known issue at this version? next step I will try moving to the latest version to see if this also resolves it.